# Linux Mint 17.2 graphic card not recognize 1060 gtx

Tags: linux-mint, gnu-screen, graphic-card

I came here because I have a issue with my new graphic card (1060 GTX) on Linux Mint 17.2. The graphic card works perfectly on Windows.

When I choose Linux Mint from the Grub, the screen become black and after a few moments, my monitor is like any device has been not detected.

I don't have more informations.
What can I do to fix that ?

Comment: Did my answer work?

Comment: Sorry I just moved into my new apartment, I do not yet have had time to try, I test it this weekend thank you very much :)

Comment: What is the exact reseller of your card (MSI, EVGA, Asus…)? I had the same issue, resolved by installing nvidia proprietary drivers (it seems nouveau open-source drivers fails, but log files shows nothing interesting).

Answer (score 1):

When you see the grub screen, select the default option and press the `e` key.

Then go to the line that has the `quiet` and `splash` options.

Go to the end of this line and add `nomodeset` and then press Ctrl+x.

You'll most likely boot into the graphic interface, and then, you can install the required drivers.